# Click on nav-tabs (Bootstrap)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a question:

I want to, when click on a nav-tab, call a function on file.ts. How can I do that?

Comment: did you try using a click handler? `(click)="yourFunction()"`, for example?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happen

Comment: well you should provide *a lot* more information in your question to help others to help you.  With what you have supplied so far, it's not really clear why a click handler wouldn't work, and anything anyone might offer would just be a guess.

Comment: please show your sample code